# How to auto Generate Critical Path CSS using Penthouse or Critical for Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, critical, criticalpathcss

How to auto Generate Critical Path CSS using Penthouse or Critical for Magento 2.

**Reff:**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/penthouse

https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical

Answer (score 3):

You can use [magento-2-gulp](https://github.com/bobmotor/magento-2-gulp) implementation to compile critical CSS.

If you use default Magento `grunt`, you can install [grunt-penthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-penthouse) and add new task.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  penthouse: {
    extract : {
        outfile : '.tmp/out.css',
        css : './dist/css/full.css',
        url : 'http://localhost:9000',
        width : 1300,
        height : 900,
        skipErrors : false // this is the default
    },
  },
});
```

The same for the [gulp-penthouse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-penthouse) if you have your own gulp configuration.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var criticalCss = require('gulp-penthouse');

gulp.task('critical-css', function () {
    return gulp.src('./styles.css')
        .pipe(criticalCss({
            out: 'critical.css',
            url: 'http://localhost:9000',
            width: 1300,
            height: 900,
            strict: true,
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});
```

Example for `gulp`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var criticalCss = require('gulp-penthouse');

gulp.task('critical-css', function () {
    return gulp
        .src([
            'pub/static/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/en_US/css/styles-l.css', 
            'pub/static/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/en_US/css/styles-m.css'
        ], {
            base: 'pub/static/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/en_US/css/'
        })
        .pipe(criticalCss({
            out: 'critical.css',
            url: 'http://<yoursite>.loc',
            width: 1300,
            height: 900,
            strict: true,
            userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/design/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/web/css'));
});
```

Comment: should we use the above snippet inside the module.exports = function (grunt) {}) of Gruntfile.js in Magento root
and simply run grunt exec? or are there any steps to follow?